# I want to automatically launch installed applications when my Oculus Go/Quest/Quest 2 machine is turned on

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, oculusquest, oculusgo

I want to run the installed application automatically when the device is turned on.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know how it is.

Comment: Hello welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to provide more insight about what you want to achieve. Can you give code example, documentation so we can help you ?